# How do I access this Javascript array (JSON object?)?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, string

My problem is that the database fields have been badly designed by previous people before me. We are accessing the table rows horizontally.

I am working with PHP and jQuery right now and I am passing data back and forth through AJAX. In PHP I am accessing this array like so:

```
$attendance['date_lesson_' . $lessonCount]
```

where lessonCount is a number from 1-10 that is incremented i.e. if `lessonCount = 1` then above would be `$attendance['date_lesson_1']`

I am passing the attendance array through `json_encode`

How do I therefore access this field `data_lesson_` 1 up to 10 in jQuery?

I am trying to do:

```
var lessonCount = 1;

attendance[i].date_lesson_+lessonCount

//do some stuff with attendance.date_lesson_ 
lessonCount++;
```

It was easy in PHP cause you concatenate strings with the dot `"."` but this isn't a string I'm dealing with in jQuery/JavaScript so how on earth would I do this?

Yes, I know. This is awkward. I agree 100%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’ll need to use bracket notation:

```
attendance['date_lesson_' + lessonCount]
```

[Dot notation can only be used with identifier names as property names.](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, I don't know how that json looks like.

```
attendance["date_lesson_"+lessonCount]
```

Comment: I refrained from showing the JSON because it's 50 fields long...
(when it could have been 5)